# mysql select where count more than x

Tags: mysql

How can I create a MySQL query that requires the count of total for same query to be over x?

Eg

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from DB where BANANAS='1' and ORANGES='2' and [COUNT OF THIS QUERY IS MORE THAN 5]");
```

Thanks!

M

***EDIT***

to be more clear... , what Im looking for is:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from DB where BANANAS='1' and ORANGES='2' group by PINEAPPLES order by SUM(SUGAR) desc limit 1 and [[[COUNT OF PINEAPLES WHERE BANANAS='1' IS MORE THAN 5]]]");
```

hope that helped...

Comment: [COUNT OF THIS QUERY IS MORE THAN 5] what you mean by this

Comment: What are you grouping by?

Comment: You want all the rows (that match the criteria) but only if they are 6 or more?

Answer (score 3):

`and (select count(*) from foo where bar) > 5`

or

`group by baz having count(*) > 5`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you ask for. But if you want all the rows (that match the criteria) but only if they are 6 or more, here is one way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName         -- have you really named your table "DB"?
WHERE bananas = 1 
  AND oranges = 2
  AND ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tableName 
        WHERE bananas = 1 
          AND oranges = 2
      ) > 5 ;
```

and another:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName         -- have you really named your table "DB"?
WHERE bananas = 1 
  AND oranges = 2
  AND ( SELECT 1
        FROM tableName 
        WHERE bananas = 1 
          AND oranges = 2
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
      ) IS NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selection to take place only if the count is more than 5, then the following query might be useful.

```
select count(*) from DB as X where BANANAS='1' and ORANGES='2';

select * from DB where BANANAS='1' and ORANGES='2' IF (CAST(X as UNSIGNED) > 5);
```